# Can we run future function after app is terminated/kill

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I was trying to call a function when app is killed to store a record in database, and to execute it I was trying to implement when AppLifeCycleState is detached but as app is terminated code execution is stopped as well. So Is there anyway to achieve it.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tracker_app/core/life.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const simpleTaskKey = "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simpleTask";
const failedTaskKey = "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.failedTask";
const simpleDelayedTask = "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simpleDelayedTask";
const simplePeriodicTask =
    "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simplePeriodicTask";
const simplePeriodic1HourTask =
    "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simplePeriodic1HourTask";

@pragma(
    'vm:entry-point') // Mandatory if the App is obfuscated or using Flutter 3.1+
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case simpleTaskKey:
        log("$simpleTaskKey was executed. inputData = $inputData");
        // final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        // prefs.setBool("test", true);
        // print("Bool from prefs: ${prefs.getBool("test")}");
        break;
      case failedTaskKey:
        log('failed task');
        return Future.error('failed');
      case simpleDelayedTask:
        log("$simpleDelayedTask was executed");
        break;
      case simplePeriodicTask:
        log("$simplePeriodicTask was executed");
        break;
      case simplePeriodic1HourTask:
        log("$simplePeriodic1HourTask was executed");
        break;
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode: true,
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(LifecycleEventHandler(
     ///I want this function to be executed when app is terminated
      detachedCallBack: () async {
        await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
          simpleTaskKey,
          simpleTaskKey,
          inputData: <String, dynamic>{
            'int': 1,
            'bool': true,
            'double': 1.0,
            'string': 'string',
            'array': [1, 2, 3],
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter WorkManager Example"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Plugin initialization",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                ),

                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Register failed Task"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
                      simpleTaskKey,
                      simpleTaskKey,
                      inputData: <String, dynamic>{
                        'int': 1,
                        'bool': true,
                        'double': 1.0,
                        'string': 'string',
                        'array': [1, 2, 3],
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                //This task runs once
                //This wait at least 10 seconds before running
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Register Delayed OneOff Task"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
                        simpleDelayedTask,
                        simpleDelayedTask,
                        initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
                      );
                    }),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                //This task runs periodically
                //It will wait at least 10 seconds before its first launch
                //Since we have not provided a frequency it will be the default 15 minutes
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Register Periodic Task (Android)"),
                    onPressed: Platform.isAndroid
                        ? () {
                            Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
                              simplePeriodicTask,
                              simplePeriodicTask,
                              initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
                            );
                          }
                        : null),
                //This task runs periodically
                //It will run about every hour
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Register 1 hour Periodic Task (Android)"),
                    onPressed: Platform.isAndroid
                        ? () {
                            Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
                              simplePeriodicTask,
                              simplePeriodic1HourTask,
                              frequency: Duration(hours: 1),
                            );
                          }
                        : null),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  "Task cancellation",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Cancel All"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await Workmanager().cancelAll();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code is Updated,

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(LifecycleEventHandler(
      detachedCallBack: () async {
        await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
          simpleTaskKey,
          simpleTaskKey,
          inputData: <String, dynamic>{
            'int': 1,
            'bool': true,
            'double': 1.0,
            'string': 'string',
            'array': [1, 2, 3],
          },
        );
      },
    ));
```

I want to run this block of code when app is terminated

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can Use flutter's [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package

Here is the Code Snippet for it.

```
 const myTask = "syncWithTheBackEnd";
void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  Workmanager.registerOneOffTask(
    "1",
    myTask, //This is the value that will be returned in the callbackDispatcher
    initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 5),
    constraints: WorkManagerConstraintConfig(
      requiresCharging: true,
      networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task) {
    switch (task) {
      case myTask:
        print("this method was called from native!");
        break;
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        break;
    }
    //Return true when the task executed successfully or not
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

checkout [this](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/flutter-executing-a-task-after-app-is-killed) article it has more detailed example

Comment: It is not helping me I will update my code can you please help me where I might be wrong

Comment: Is log getting printed in case simpleTaskKey ?

Comment: when button clicked yes, but in termination nothing is happening, Log gets terminated as well